# How to understand the queueStream API in apache spark?

Tags: apache-spark

pyspark has a api queueStream used to construct dstream from a series of rdd.

```
queueStream(rdds, oneAtATime=True, default=None)
Create an input stream from an queue of RDDs or list. In each batch, it will process either one or all of the RDDs returned by the queue.

NOTE: changes to the queue after the stream is created will not be recognized.

Parameters: 
rdds – Queue of RDDs
oneAtATime – pick one rdd each time or pick all of them once.
default – The default rdd if no more in rdds
```

Question 1:

In a distributed environment, if I define a queue object q1. And I do the operation like q1.add(RDD). Will the q1 object transferred to all worker nodes? Will there be problem for the operation q1.add(RDD) if this object are copied to other nodes?

Question 2:

After I run dstream = queueStream(q1). 
If I continue to put RDD in the queue. Will these RDDS be added to the dstream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the following note:

> changes to the queue after the stream is created will not be recognized.

pretty much answers the question but to understand why this is the case you'll have to at the PySpark code, in particular [following line](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4f60651cbec1b4c9cc2e6d832ace77e89a233f3a/python/pyspark/streaming/context.py#L323):

```
queue = self._jvm.PythonDStream.toRDDQueue([r._jrdd for r in rdds])
```

If this not enough you can take a look at [the corresponding Scala code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/645c3a85e2029928d37ec2de9ef5a2d884620b9b/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/api/python/PythonDStream.scala#L182-L187) to see that it takes a static list:

```
def toRDDQueue(rdds: JArrayList[JavaRDD[Array[Byte]]])
```

and converts it to a queue:

```
val queue = new java.util.LinkedList[JavaRDD[Array[Byte]]]
rdds.asScala.foreach(queue.add)
```

So there is simply no way for any changes on the Python side to be reflected in the stream.

Regarding the first question the answer is negative. Queue won't be distributed because RDD are simply not meaningful outside `Driver` context.

**Note**:

To be clear, Scala `queueStream` will reflect additions to the queue. [There is even an example in  the Spark source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/68ed3632c56389ab3ff4ea5d73c575f224dab4f6/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/QueueStream.scala#L26)

Comment: So there really is no way to get DStream from a continued stream of RDDs ?  With python

Comment: All "standard" methods (file streams, Kafka streams) will work just fine. With some effort you could actually build a wrapper around the queue as well but synchronization is ... even without going through gateway.

Comment: @zero323 Is the above question still stands true that still there is no way to get DStream from a continued streams of RDD's in python